# Standard deviation of percentage changes in a time course

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, standard-deviation

I ran into a problem analysing some data I produced. I measured concentrations in biological samples in a time course manner. I measured three replicates for each of the seven time points. I can display the data as means +- SD, that's easy.

Now I want to express the data as percent changes relative to the first time point. I am completely clueless on how to apply SD or any other measurement of variability to the percentages. Sorry if this is a double post, but the other answers somehow don't fit to my problem.

Another problem I will run into soon is the following: I will analyze a different genotype in the same manner and want to test for significant differences between the genotypes. Any recommendation for a test? Preferably something that can be done in Excel, I am just beginning to learn R.

Answer (score 2):

You can still calculate SD for percent change the same way as you normally do.  However, keep in mind that the distribution for percent change may be different (skewed or otherwise non-normal) so check your assumptions.  But you should be able to run a standard t-test or ANOVA otherwise.  Just realize that your SD will be different.  Often a better way of analyzing change from baseline (instead of percent change) is to model the dependent variable while putting the baseline value as a covariate in the model (i.e, in a regression or ANCOVA).  Then you don't need to worry about a different SD for percent change.

Answer (score 2):

Percent change is not a quantity for which it is appropriate to compute the mean, much less the standard deviation.  That is because of the inherent asymmetry of percents.  An increase of 100% is balanced by a decrease of 50%.  So if you need to consider relative change, analyze log ratios.  The advice from @Bosley to use ANCOVA is even better.

Comment: is your statement true in the case that one is analyzing percent change for test-retest data, as well?

Comment: Absolutely.  More information is at http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/ManuscriptChecklist under the heading Inappropriate choice of measure of change.